# Uwp app is getting crashed with error - Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: uwp, crash

Is this error related to not having enough disk space or the system's memory full usage?

Another client also got crashed with an error - Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

Are these two errors are same and the issue is with my code?

Comment: Have you tried repair the OS or update to latest version?

Comment: Yes. It seems the issue is with my code. But I am not able to figure out where exactly.

Comment: Any code could share to reproduce this problem?